# How to enable PHP Scripts with Folderpath like Wordpress or Zend?

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

How can i archieve permalink urls with php scripts? 
I mean something like wordpress does for it posts like

```
url: www.example.com/year/entry 

$year = ...
$entry = ...
```

without having the actual folder created ... 
I dont want to use .htacess because Wordpress does not use it either i think.

Normal behaviour would be a 404 Error because the folder does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mod rewrite in Apache (different servers will allow different rewriting mechanisms).

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Most of the time the rewrites are done using regex. Here is an example (i will explain what it does after) that you put in a .htaccess file in the root directory of your site ie: http://website.com/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^js/main.js$ /scripts/main.php [L]
```

That will allow you to enter the following in your browser: http://website.com/main.js But the file will actually be located on the server at http://website.com/scripts/main.php and the files can be located OUT of the public directory for better security.

Another example but this time using a little more regex

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^js/([0-9a-f]+).js$ /scripts/main.php [L]
```

Allows all these to go to the same file:

- http://website.com/abc018.js
- http://website.com/fbc01.js
- http://website.com/8bc18.js

will all load http://website.com/scripts/main.php

P.S. The [L] indicates to the server that it's the LAST rewrite and it does not need to keep looking for matches.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Zend Router to tell your application where to go when certain url is requested. You would not have to create the folder, you just need to match the path to the correct controller/action.

[Zend Router Docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.standard)

For WordPress you can simply use a plugin. This should be fairly streight-foward to do. [Check out this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-router/)

Comment: thanks for your answer but i am looking for a way to do it on my own for very little custom scripts that dont rely on wordpress or zend.

Comment: Then you are going to have to use either .httaccess or your urls can look like this /index.php/company/info. This will request index.php where you can easily redirect or show the appropriate content.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress does use mod-rewrite & .htaccess otherwise you would have seen index.php in the page link.

You may do the same, use mod-rewrite & make a php file to handle the requested path.